# Music is getting stopped when application come from background to foreground

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am developing the chat application , If someone sends any message to me & my app is in background then i receive that message and i play the tone whenever message received,while tone is playing in mean while application is opened  then music is getting stopped . How to make it continue when app comes to foreground also. (Tone must be complete as per duration available init). How to solve this issue. Waiting for the answer.

Comment: are you using push notification for getting message when your app in background ?.

Comment: I am using local notication using xmpp server my chatting is happening

Answer (score 2):

You have to work on remote control received events with notification..

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)theEvent {

    if (theEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl)  {
        switch(theEvent.subtype)        {
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TogglePlayPause" object:nil];
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TogglePlayPause" object:nil];
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop:
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TogglePlayPause" object:nil];
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

[you can view complete answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591421/ios-background-audio-not-playing/22777813#22777813)

Comment: Thanks for answering . But i am playing my tone using UILocalnotification. Then i am having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use AVAudioSession. You can have the music temporarily pause or lower in volume while alert plays, then it'll resume full force!

First to initialize audio:

```
AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil]
[audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
Playing the sound (AVAudioPlayer's play/prepareToPlay will activate the audio session for you):

AVAudioPlayer* audioPlayer = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:nil];
[audioPlayer play];
```

Stopping the alert sound:

```
[audioPlayer stop];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withFlags:AVAudioSessionSetActiveFlags_NotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];
```

The flag kAudioSessionSetActiveFlag_NotifyOthersOnDeactivation tells the system to notify background audio to resume playing after the sound is played.

Comment: Thanks for answering . But i am playing my tone using UILocalnotification. Then i am having this issue.Please give me answer in this way.