# AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient does not allow me to record the voice

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiorecorder, mpmusicplayercontroller

I m working on an application in which i have to record the voice and play.it works fine,but when i write `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];` in AppDelegate it will not allow me to record the voice.
Any idea ?! i want to listen the recorded voice with background music.

Comment: Try to use AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord category

Comment: i tried,but then background music stops.

Comment: if you want to play background music also then look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591421/ios-background-audio-not-playing/22777813#22777813

Comment: Thanks.but i don't want to play my voice recording in background.
let us say i am listening music from iTunes and when i press Record button in my App.AVAudioRecorder doesn't start recording.I have check the state of MPMusicplayer and Pause it,then start recording.but fails. :(

Comment: I have the same problem as you with live streaming audio..