# ios 8 background alarm sound

Tags: swift, background, alarm

I did a lot of research and couldn't find a proper solution for my problem.
I want to make an iPhone app that plays a custom sound even when it is in background at a certain time (alarm clock app).
I did a research on the following points:

- Local Notification ->  no sound longer than 30 seconds allowed
- Background Audio -> Apple refuses Apps that don't continuously run music in background, also there is no way to trigger sound when receiving a local notification

Is there any way to achieve this, i mean there has to be one.. i found dozens of apps in the app store that support playing sounds from your library even in background, and not only 30 seconds long (this one for instance: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/background-alarm-clock-free/id723243753?mt=8)

If possible in swift.

Comment: It's objective-c, but this answer appears to address your issues:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591421/ios-background-audio-not-playing

Comment: hm.. not exactly.. it's not shown how to trigger it from the background when a notification fires (or similar)

Comment: @iVentis did u find a solution to this , to play music in background when alarm pop comes up

Comment: @Mr.G unfortunately not, in the end i did it with a 30 seconds alarm.. there seems to be no other way instead of this: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/alarm-clock-apps-ios/

Comment: @iVentis i was trying to run the alarm tone when the app is in the background, were u able to do it  ?

Comment: @Mr.G no, as i said.. in the end i went with the 30 seconds sound of the notification itself.. the only way to fire the sound in the "backround" (at least that i found) is this: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/alarm-clock-apps-ios/

Comment: but if u can take a look about this app,  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/step-out-bed!-smart-alarm/id673120263?mt=8 this has the capability to run in background mode , but only if the app is in the background , and sometimes it works sometimes, it doesnt ,  i think they are firing  this using beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler