# iOS Swift How to play AudioServicesPlaySystemSound or AudioServicesPlayAlertSound in background

Tags: ios, swift, audio

```
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    print("userNotificationCenter-UNNotificationPresentationOptions")
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option

//    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(1016)
      AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1016)
      completionHandler([.alert,.badge])
    }
```

if fcm push send in foreGround Audio is play

but in backGround  not played audio

how to play `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` or `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound`
in background
Capabilities Background Modes already Checked

Swift 4 , iOS 11

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up the background mode for play audio, to be able to do this. It's described in detail in this answer [iOS background audio not playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591421/ios-background-audio-not-playing).

[image]